# Floating-point arithmetic M(10,6,6)

Tags: arithmetic

Consider arithmetic $M(10,6,6)$, (decimal system, 6 places for mantissa, 6 places for exponent). I have to find the largest positive and smallest positive number in this arithmetic. I   was looking for clues. But, I don't know how to do this.
Example for $M(2,3,3)$:
[image]

Comment: You should have a specific definition of what each piece means.  You have not specified a sign anywhere.  Is it hidden in the mantissa?  It would seem likely the greatest exponent is $999999$ or $+99999$ or some such.  By smallest do you mean the most negative or the closest positive number to zero?  Please think about the problem and improve your question.

Comment: You're right. I mean positive numbers. So, this is an example of task for exam. I have example for $M(2,3,3)$. Could you want to see?